# Improve performance with the WHERE NOT IN sub-select clause

Tags: performance, subquery, firebird, execution-plan, query-performance

In the following query, I have to count transactions for each customer.  However, I have to exclude from the result set entirely, customers that have a transaction older than one year.

Shouldn't the query optimizer be smart enough to only evaluate existence once for each customer?

```
--Count transactions on customers that are less than 1 year old

SELECT t1.CUSTID, COUNT(*)
FROM CUST_TRX t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
  SELECT FIRST 1 1 
  FROM CUST_TRX t2 
  WHERE 
    t2.CUSTID = t1.CUSTID AND
    t2.DATED < CURRENT_DATE - 365
  GROUP BY t2.CUSTID
)
GROUP BY t1.CUSTID
```

There are no naturals in my query plan. This query is performing as if the database is running the existence clause for every transaction instead of running it for every customer. Performance is the same if I remove the `GROUP BY` in the subquery.

Is there a better way to do this so that I may get better performance out of the database?  Hopefully a simple `SELECT` query will work avoiding a CTE if possible (that would introduce other challenges).

Due to other `GROUP BY` criteria (not shown here) I'm not able to simply check `MIN(DATED)`, I really need to perform another query.

Comment: What indexes are there on the table? What is the actual query and what is the execution plan of the actual query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With queries like this is it often more efficient to perform a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of the `NOT EXISTS` style check, *it often implies a full index scan (or table scan without the right indexes in place) but with many rows in the main table(s) this is less expensive than the large number of index seeks (one on the reference table for each row returned from the main table) that would otherwise result*. Some query planners are quite bright about spotting this equivalence and using the alternate plan where it is the better choice, but it doesn't sound like this has happened in your case.

Try something like:

```
SELECT t1.CUSTID, COUNT(*)
FROM   CUST_TRX t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
       CUST_TRX t2 
ON     t2.CUSTID=t1.CUSTID 
AND    t2.DATED<CURRENT_DATE-365
WHERE  t2.CUSTID IS NULL
GROUP BY t1.CUSTID
```

(note: I'm not familiar with firebird, so the above syntax may need tweaks but should illustrate the point)

Without the `WHERE  t2.CUSTID IS NULL` every row from `t1` with matches in `t2` will be output once for every match found in `t2` and those with no matches in `t2` will be output once but with any columns selected from that object set to NULL. The `WHERE` clause then screens out the matches.

Depending on the DB engine's abilities, especially if the amount of data in the reference object (`CUST_TRX` with a filter applied here) is huge, this may be significantly *less* efficient than the `WHERE <something> NOT IN` or `WHERE NOT EXISTS` options, so benchmark over realistic data sets first before using the method. It often works out much more efficient with MS SQL Server in cases where the query planner doesn't notice that the `WHERE NOT IN` arrangement can be performed this way more efficiently.

Also if you do it this way around leave a comment in the code (and/or supporting documentation) to say that you are doing this as an equivalent to `WHERE <something> NOT IN` or `WHERE NOT EXISTS` which you expect to be more efficient. You'll remember it and an experienced SQL person will recognise the pattern, but other people looking at the code might not immediately understand the intent/reason and flip it back to using `WHERE NOT EXISTS` for clarity as that reads better as on English sentence.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "count transactions on customers that are less than 1 year old" do you mean:

1. Count all customer transactions that are less than one year old?
2. Count all transactions for new customers less than one year old?

From the sample code I understand that #1 is what you want.  In that case, do you really need a WHERE NOT EXISTS?  Could you just do something like:

```
SELECT t1.CUSTID, COUNT(*)
FROM CUST_TRX t1
WHERE t1.DATED>=CURRENT_DATE-365
GROUP BY t1.CUSTID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
```

I am not a Firebird user, but I looked up the GROUP BY / HAVING syntax.

[EDIT]Exclude from the result set customers that have a transaction older than one year.

OK, the here is other take on aggregating the rows to eliminate customer from the select.

```
SELECT A.CUSTID, A.HowMany
FROM (SELECT t1.CUSTID, COUNT(*) HowMany, MIN(t1.DATED) OldestTran
    FROM CUST_TRX t1
    GROUP BY t1.CUSTID
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 0 AND MIN(t1.DATED) >=CURRENT_DATE-365) AS A
```

[EDIT] OK, so the query is more complex that can be embodied in a single query.

This means that you will likely need to use a pattern much like the one you first posted. Note that EXISTS implies a DISTINCT and is often faster than a JOIN from a SELECT DISTINCT. But you can try different approaches and compare the behavior, timing, etc.  Then choose the one that you like the best.

Comment: I have to exclude from the result set entirely, customers that have a transaction older than one year.